# State Machine with State per Entity

Tags: xna, c#, design-patterns, fsm

I have a generic state machine implementation like this:

```
public abstract class State<TOwner>
{
    public virtual void OnEnter(TOwner owner) { ... }

    public virtual void OnExit(TOwner owner) { ... }
}

public sealed class StateMachine<TOwner, TState>
    where TState : State<TOwner>
{
    public TState CurrentState { ... }
}
```

Usage looks a bit like this (more or less):

```
public abstract class SoldierState : State<Soldier>
{
    public abstract void Update(Soldier owner, GameTime gameTime);
}

public class RestState : SoldierState
{
    public static readonly RestState Instance = new RestState();

    private RestState()
    {
    }

    public override void Update(Soldier owner, GameTime gameTime) { ... }
}

public class Soldier
{
    private readonly StateMachine<Soldier, SoldierState> state = ...;

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        this.state.CurrentState.Update(this, gameTime);
    }
}
```

Importantly, notice how my state classes are singletons. This means every soldier will share the same `SoldierState` instances.

This is fine until I need to store state per soldier. For example, suppose I want to ensure that soldiers remain in the rest state for a minimum of 10 seconds. That means that any soldier that enters the rest state needs to have an associated piece of data tracked for it.

I could just use a dictionary:

```
public class RestState : SoldierState
{
    ...

    private readonly IDicionary<Soldier, TimeSpan> restTimes = ...;

    public override void Update(Soldier owner, GameTime gameTime) 
    {
        TimeSpan restTime;
        restTimes.TryGetValue(owner, out restTime);
        restTime += gameTime.Elapsed;

        if (restTime > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
        {
            soldier.State = FightingState.Instance;
            restTimes.Remove(soldier);
        }
        else
        {
            restTimes[soldier] = restTime;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm concerned about the efficiency (or lack thereof) here. Is there a better way to achieve what I want? Would I be better off having state instances per entity instead of trying to use singletons?

Comment: Quite probably you would be better with one per entity.  It sounds like whatever requirement prompted you to create the singletons is no longer valid, therefore a refactor is called for.

Comment: Agree with Patrick, it seems silly to try to keep a global state for your soldiers, if you want them to be able to have different states.

Comment: Fair point. The reason I went with singletons was to make it as simple as possible to change states (by assigning the singleton). By having one state per entity, I need to store references to both the state machine and to the individual states. Not likely a big problem, but something I was trying to avoid if possible.

Comment: Moveover, those state instances will have to be exposed by my soldier so that other states can use them to switch states. eg. `RestState` above will need to do something like `soldier.State = soldier.FightingState;` Doing some refactoring now...